# Проблема "Could not resolve import from source"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, venv

Коллеги, я работаю в vscode, в каждом новом проекте я создаю виртуальное окружение командой `python3 -m venv venv`, а активирую его `source venv/bin/activate`.

При этом возникает следующая проблема - все мои импорты подсвечивают желтым, и по ним вылетают предупреждения:

```
Could not resolve import from source.
```

В то же самое время, в правом нижнем углу у меня выбирается системный интерпретатор питон по умолчанию, а не тот, который стоит у меня в окружении.

Я нашел единственное решение - при возникновении проблемы я сохраняю зависимости в requirements txt, удаляю окружение и создаю новое через консоль vscode (create environment), после чего устанавливаю зависимости. В таком случае все начинает работать.

Но ведь такая работа - это не нормально, поэтому обращаюсь к вам, возможно, кто-то с такой проблемой сталкивался и может подсказать.
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Создавайте окружение, в vscode выбирайте интерпретатор из него внизу справа. Вроде бы после этого vscode сам окружение активирует (но это не точно). Ничего удалять/пересоздавать не нужно.

Comment: Дело в том, что в правом нижнем углу не выбирается интерпретатор из виртуального окружения, там только уже установленные глобально версии, через path оно тоже не включается, поэтому и возникает проблема. Я так понимаю, мое виртуальное окружение просто не видно системе, когда я его активирую.

Comment: Ну, в качестве догадки: у вас подключено расширение code runner - его нужно отключить или удалить. Тогда должно корректно работать при выборе интерпретатора из окружения.

Comment: Я проверил список расширений, такого расширения у меня нет.

Comment: В общем, активация окружения через source влияет только на терминал, где команда выполняется, оно не активируется "в системе", и не активируется в vscode. Для vscode нужно именно выбирать интерпретатор внизу справа из виртуального окружения, тогда должно работать. Еще, проверьте что у вас проект как папка открыт, тогда созданное виртуальное окружение должно отображаться в списке интерпретаторов.

Comment: Мне помогло то, что я открыл explorer в левом окне, когда он открыт, vscode видит окружение, запускает его и выбирает правильный интерпретатор. В общем все заработало, большое спасибо!
Но не очень понятно, почему vscode с закрытым окном explorer не может этого сделать.

Comment: explorer вообще никаким боком влиять не может.

Comment: Я из интереса попробовал открыть питон файл из обычной папки, дальше в терминале vscode ввел команду для запуска окружения, и интерпретатор не поменялся, повылезали ошибки из заголовка, а когда я выбрал фолдер в эксплорере, все пришло в порядок, и интерпретатор выбрался, и импорты перестали подсвечиваться ошибкой.